# Selected tbody not removing from multiple tbody(s) with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I know it is a very simple query but I have spent my whole day to make it work but no luck. I am trying to remove any tbody with its ID but it's not removing by any of method I found on the net. What mistake I am doing here?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
      alert('clicked');
      //    $('#td1').html('');
      //   $('#td1').remove();
      $('#td1').empty();
      //   $('#td1').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
</script>
<p>(tbody have dummy content for testing. please ignore.)</p>
<table>
  <tbody id="td1">
    qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="td2">
    wwwwwwwwwwwwww
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="td3">
    eeeeeeeeeeeeeee
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" name="complete" value="click" id="btn" />
```

I am getting this layout from a CMS where I want to delete selected "tbody".

Comment: on button click, how do you know which `tbody` to remove?

Comment: which has ID td1

Comment: do you want to remove or empty the content?

Comment: actually I want to remove but empty will do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first set the semantics of the table correctly, ie have `tr` and `td`. The you can use `remove()` or `empty()` as per your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#td1').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody id="td1">
    <tr>
      <td>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="td2">
    <tr>
      <td>wwwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="td3">
    <tr>
      <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" name="complete" value="click" id="btn" />
```

Comment: Ok thanks,  it means only tbody not consider as element.

Comment: here only tbody means like I did above without td and tr.

Answer (score 2):

You td hide using display none property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#td1').css('display','none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>(tbody have dummy content for testing. please ignore.)</p>
<table>
  <tbody id="td1">
    <tr>
      <td>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="td2">
    <tr>
      <td>wwwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="td3">
    <tr>
      <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" name="complete" value="click" id="btn" />
```